# How print values in arrays in array, inside multiple objects

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [
    {
        infoType: [
            [1],
            [2],
            [3],
        ]
    },
    {
        infoType: [
            [4],
            [5],
            [6],
        ]   
    },
    {
        infoType: [
            [7],
            [7],
            [8],
        ]   
    },
    {
        infoType: [
            [9],
            [10],
            [11],
        ]   
    }

]
```

Guys, i have this data with several objects inside, and inside this objects i have a field 'infoType', and i'm trying to print all the values, but i am not getting.

How can i do that?

I was trying like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].infoType.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(item);
    })
}


for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 for(var j = 0; i < data[i].infoType.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].infoType[j]);
 }
}
```

I can'T use jquery for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `item[0]` because `item` is also an **array** of length `1`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].infoType.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(item[0]);
    })
}
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/p42ny7n9/)**

Answer (score 1):

i have done this solution before array in array. but in c# side for google maps markers

```
str.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    str.Append("var _arrSitesLatLang = new Array();");

    StationsDataDB objSitesDB = new StationsDataDB();
    DataTable dt = objSitesDB.GetBySitesIdAndDates(Request.QueryString["SId"], Request.QueryString["date"], Request.QueryString["Q"]);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        str.Append("var arr = new Array();");
        str.Append("arr.push('" + dt.Rows[i]["Station"].ToString() + "');");
        string[] latlang = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i]["LatLang"].ToString()))
        {
            latlang = dt.Rows[i]["LatLang"].ToString().Trim().Split(',');
            str.Append("arr.push(" + latlang[0] + ");");
            str.Append("arr.push(" + latlang[1] + ");");
        }
        str.Append("_arrSitesLatLang.push(arr);");
    }
```

and in the client side

```
var markers = _arrSitesLatLang;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Allow each marker to have an info window    
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
```

my array returns data like e.g _arrSitesLatLang = [[1,1],[1,2]] eg.

There is another Solution for this kind of work

if you use an array main and push in this array the objects and its properties. like

```
$.grep function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to flatten your structure:

```
function getValues(root, vals) {
    if (root instanceof Array){
        for (var i = 0; i < root.length;i++){
            if (typeof root[i] == 'object')
                getValues(root[i], vals);
            else
                vals.push(root[i]);
        }
        return;
    }
    for (var key in root){
        getValues(root[key], vals);
    }
}


var data = [
    {
        infoType: [
            [1],
            [2],
            [3],
        ]
    },
    {
        infoType: [
            [4],
            [5],
            [6],
        ]   
    },
    {
        infoType: [
            [7],
            [7],
            [8],
        ]   
    },
    {
        infoType: [
            [9],
            [10],
            [11],
        ]   
    }

];
var vals = [];
getValues(data, vals);
console.log(vals);
```

After the structure is flat you just can itarte over the vals variable as a simple array:

```
for (var i = 0; i< vals.length; i++){
    console.log(vals[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print all values in the above structure, and **assuming no other structure is introduced** you can do:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhtxrjy3/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i].infoType;
    for (var j =0; j < obj.length; j++) {
        console.log(obj[j][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be also helpful... to print values...

```
data.map( a => a.infoType.map( b => b[0] ) ).flat()
```